# c#: Problems with the namespaces

Tags: c#, namespaces, project

I am having a problem with Visual Studio 2015 and Framework 4.6.1.

I have a business layer with this namespace: `BusinessLayer.LocalStorage`. In this class (named LocalStorage) I have this function:

```
...    
public static void XXX()
{
}
...
```

In the main project with the same Framework 4.6.1, I have in one Winform

```
using BusinessLayer.LocalStorage;
```

In the Load I wrote the function but the reference is not recognized:

[image]

I have to add *LocalStorage* before:

```
LocalStorage.LocalStorage.XXX();
```

This way the call is working

why is not working using LocalStorage.XXX()? I declared my namespace in the using clausules.. Then should be working.

I have the class in a directory inside BusinessLayer project for this reason namespace should be *BusinessLayer.LocalStorage*

Code is:

```
namespace BusinessLayer.LocalStorage 
{
  public class LocalStorage 
  {
     ...
     public static void XXX() 
     {
     }
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for your LocalStorage class and your main class?

Comment: Remember class is inside a directory called LocalStorage for this reason the namespace is BussinessLayer.LocalStorage. I added the class code

Comment: The full name of your class is `BussinessLayer.LocalStorage.LocalStorage`, and `LocalStorage` alone is ambiguous, `LocalStorage.LocalStorage` is not. I would advise you to rename or the other as having a namespace and a class inside named the same means there is not a clear distinction between responsibilities of the namespace (group of functionality) and the class (one piece of functionality).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `LocalStorage` is ambiguous, it could either be namespace `LocalStorage` or the class `LocalStorage`. You can solve this in 3 ways:

1. Remove the namespace `LocalStorage` entirely and move everything in it inside the `BusinessLayer` namespace
2. Rename the class `LocalStorage` to something else
3. Add `using LocalStorage = BusinessLayer.LocalStorage.LocalStorage` to the top of your file where you need to use the class `LocalStorage`

---

**Edit**: Option 4. If you desperately want to keep the directory structure as it is right now (with a LocalStorage directory), you can alternatively tell Visual Studio that the directory LocalStorage is not a namespace provider. You can do this by editing the properties of the folder in the Solution Explorer

Comment: I tried it, I don't like the idea because I would like to use only the class name when I calling it with the clausule using. Was strange the behavior. Of course it is working with alias.

Comment: The main problem is that you have a namespace and a class named the same, that makes it impossible for the compiler to know what you mean at any given place, so there is no strange behaivour, only intended behaivour

Comment: @David I just edited my answer to include a fourth option which may suit your needs better

Comment: I will use this method, aftyer test it is the best (it was I was doing before ask)

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio automatically generates Namespaces based on the current location of a class within a solution. When you create a new class it first takes the name of the project. Then it takes the current folder the class is located in. it will continue appending the folder name to the namespace until it reaches the class name itself.

So for example, if you have a project called ExampleProject, with a folder called Models, with a class inside called BaseModel.cs, the resulting namespace would be `ExampleProject.Models`

Make sure the namespace containing XXX is not LocalStorage.LocalStorage and is called BusinessLayer.LocalStorage. You can change this namespace to whatever you want and rebuild your project.

Comment: "resulting namespace would be ExampleProject.Models.BaseModel" not really, the resulting namespace would be `ExampleProject.Models` which contains a class `BaseModel`, so `using ExampleProject.Models` would give you access to `BaseModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Although the namespace structure and object names are not recommended to be the same, which will lead to errors in many cases, I see that you want to use it this way from the comments you made.

I don't recommend you to name a class like its namespace, see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one)

I would recommend would be `<XYZ>LocalStorage.cs`

I don't know your layer structure, but you can call it LocalStorage.XXX () with a structure like the one below.

BusinessLayer structure:

[image]

LocalStorage Class:

```
namespace BusinessLayer.LocalStorage
{
    public  class LocalStorage
    {
        public static void XXX()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, after referencing BusinessLayer to winForm, you can call it in Load method as follows.

[image]

```
using System;
using BusinessLayer.LocalStorage;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LocalStorage.XXX();
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you don't want a folder in your BusinessLayer structure, you can use it using the same namespace (`namespace BusinessLayer.LocalStorage`) as below.

[image]